# Quickbooks API reconnect issue

Tags: api, oauth, coldfusion, quickbooks, reconnect

I've been implementing connectivity to Quickbooks via the v3 API with ColdFusion, and have most everything working except reconnect (https://appcenter.intuit.com/api/v1/connection/reconnect).  I can get customer info, create/update invoices, etc, but no luck with reconnect.

From my app I get an Error Code 22 (Authentication required), but I'm sending the same auth header that I send for any of the other API call to access a protected resource.  The oauth spec does not specifically have a "reconnect" action so my question is what specific oauth properties need to be included in the auth header for the Quickbooks reconnect call?

From the oauth 1.0 spec is it the headers for **Consumer Requests an Access Token**?

oauth_consumer_key
oauth_token
oauth_signature_method
oauth_signature
oauth_timestamp
oauth_nonce
oauth_version
oauth_verifier

Or is it the header sent for **accessing a protected resource** 
oauth_consumer_key
oauth_token
oauth_signature_method
oauth_signature:
oauth_timestamp
oauth_nonce
oauth_version

Or, is it some other header set?

Also, I've tried using the [Dev Playgorund](https://appcenter.intuit.com/Playground/OAuth) to test reconnect, and from there I get a 
24 - Invalid App Token

So I'm at a loss at this point.  For what it's worth Disconnect works fine :)

Any help, guidance, suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please see-https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0053_auth_auth/oauth_management_api#Reconnect Error 24 means that your app is not approved for API.

Comment: We also have been receiving `<ErrorMessage>This API requires Authorization.</ErrorMessage> <ErrorCode>22</ErrorCode>` seemingly at random when calling the reconnect API. For now, we are just going to not call reconnect unless we _think_ we are within the 150-180 day window. As for testing if the token is still valid, we are going to call a simple Get method inside a try/catch wrapper.

Comment: How did you solve your issue? I am getting same error while calling reconnect api on java. Can you please post your correct answer if it working fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The first issue if you are doing things in the order you specify is that you cannot disconnect first and then subsequently reconnect. The reconnect API must be called with a valid access token, as the current access token will be invalidated and a new access token will be issued.

Secondly, there is a window for calling this API to refresh the 6 month life of the access token, it must be called in the last 30 days. This allows your app to refresh the token without prompting the customer again.

However in all cases if you disconnect, or the customer manually disconnects you cannot call the reconnect API. You need to take them through the authorize flow again.

hope that helps
Jarred

Comment: Kaneally Do you have sample java code for reconnect?

Comment: this doesn't answer the question at all.

Answer (score 1):

To test reconnect from developer playground, use the following steps-
1.  Navigate to IPP Playground- Go to Manage My Apps->Click on your app

Fill in consumer key and consumer secret in links below.

Prod: https://appcenter.intuit.com/Playground/OAuth/IA/?ck=<>&cs=<> 
Stage: https://appcenter-stage.intuit.com/Playground/OAuth/IA/?ck=<>&cs=<>

Alternatively, you can navigate to the Manage page for your app on stage or prod and click ‘Test connect to app (OAuth)’. Screen shot attached. 
2.  Enter the duration you would like for the issued OAuth tokens (e.g., 3600 for successful Reconnect) in the ‘Access Token Duration’ field. Screen shot attached. 
3.  Click on the Connect to QuickBooks button, go through OAuth flow to authorize a connection to a realm. 
4.  Under the resulting Post-Connection Interactions heading, click ‘Reconnect API Test’. Screen shot attached. 
5.  A new page will launch where your OAuth tokens are displayed. Copy these values to your application to test Reconnect

As Jarred mentioned that for dev/live apps, there is a window for calling this API to refresh the 6 month life of the access token, it must be called in the last 30 days.

Comment: this answer is not relevant to the question.

Answer (score 1):

I received this error as well. Error Code 22 (Authentication required) for me meant that the OAuth signature was wrong. This was confusing because I couldn't find this error listed in the Quickbooks documents for reconnect.

I was signing the request as a "POST" request instead of a "GET" request which is what Quickbooks requires for calls to the reconnect endpoint.